# Extract words preceding and following search terms

Tags: regex

Suppose I have a text like the following.

> The City of New York often called New York City or simply New York is
>   the most populous city in the United States. With an estimated
>   population of 8537673 distributed over a land area of about 3026
>   square miles (784 km2) New York City is also the most densely
>   populated major city in the United States.

I want to locate the n words preceding and following occurrences of the a search term. For example, n=3 and search term="New York", then

1st occurrence:

- words preceding = {The, city, of}
- words following = {often, called, New}

2nd occurrence:

- words preceding = {York, often, called}
- words following = {City, or, simply}

3rd occurence:

- words preceding = {City, or, simply}
- words following = {is, the, most}

4th occurrence:

- words preceding = {miles, 784, km2}
- words following = {City, is, also}

How can I do this using regex? I found a similar question here [Extract words surrounding a search word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17645701/extract-words-surrounding-a-search-word) but it does not consider multiple occurrences of the search term.

Attempts:

```
def search(text,n): 
word = r"\W*([\w]+)" 
groups = re.search(r'{}\W*{}{}'.format(wordn,'place',wordn), text).groups() return groups[:n],groups[n:]
```

Comment: I have seen this question before today.  This is homework.  Have you tried a regex yet?

Comment: I have tried the regex given in the link I mentioned but it is not considering multiple occurrences of the search tearm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a [positive lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) in order to handle overlapping matches:

```
re.findall(r"((?:\w+\W+){3})(?=New York((?:\W+\w+){3}))", t)
```

Result:

```
[('The City of ', ' often called New'),
 ('York often called ', ' City or simply'),
 ('City or simply ', ' is the most'),
 ('miles (784 km2) ', ' City is also')]
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try the following:

```
((?:\w+\W+){3})(?=New York((?:\W+\w+){3}))
```

and get your values in group 1 and 2

Sample Source ( [run here](https://ideone.com/XyaA6C) )

```
import re
regex = r"((?:\w+\W+){3})(?=New York((?:\W+\w+){3}))"

test_str = "The City of New York often called New York City or simply New York is the most populous city in the United States. With an estimated 2016 population of 8537673 distributed over a land area of about 3026 square miles (784 km2) New York City is also the most densely populated major city in the United States."
matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str)

for match in matches:
    print(re.sub(r'\W+', ' ', match.group(1))+"  <------>" +re.sub(r'\W+', ' ', match.group(2)))
```

[Regex 101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lCPBjp/5)

Comment: This only works for n=3. How can you make it general? Depending on the number of words given by user? You also missed the 2nd occurrence.

Comment: Well it can be done as the way you have metioned but that will mean you get the the whole as 3 words as one sentence... would that do  ? Btw, you haven't mentioned the language you want to use

Comment: Yes, that would do and I am using Python

Comment: Updated the answer plz have a look

Comment: Hm, this does not deliver the correct results (2nd occurrence missed since the matches overlap). I wonder why it was accepted...

Comment: @TimPietzcker all though it seems like my regex seems turns out to be similar as you... yet thanks for mentioning that out.. but probably this is the only that the solution could be met

Comment: I don't know what makes you people think... you are the only one in this entire world who can write regex!!!