# Remove a URL from a list element in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've used regular expressions module to get a sentence out of a string by using an adapted method from this post: [Extract words surrounding a search word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17645701/extract-words-surrounding-a-search-word)

```
re.search(r'((keyword)\W+((?:\w+\W+){,22}', sentence)
```

My resulting list looks like so:

```
['AL', 'KHOR\\r\\n<https://www.fleetmon.com/vessels/al-khor-f_0_11569260>', 'departed\\r\\nat']
```

How can I remove the url from the list element and the \r\n from the middle of the elements?
Is there a way to exclude it in the re.search that would be better than trying to remove it after I've searched?

EDIT: URL will vary as it relates to individual ships. The address is the same up to /vessels

Comment: is it the URL always "http://www.website.com/en" or is it variable? it should be useful for us to have 2 o 3 cases of URLs if it is variable.

Comment: It is variable, as it is directing you to a web page for a ship so the full web address will relate to the id of the ship so: 
`['AL', 'KHOR\\r\\n<https://www.fleetmon.com/vessels/al-khor-f_0_11569260>', 'departed\\r\\nat']`
It will be the same up to vessels. Have edited post to reflect that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
a=[e.replace("\\r\\n",'').split("<")[0] for e in a]
```

Comment: Perfect! @whackamadoodle3000 this is what I needed.  
I'm learning too, so can I make sure I understand how this works?  
I get that for each list entry it replaces every "\\r\\n" with nothing, essentially a delete function. The split I am less sure on. It splits the list element at the "<" but what is the zero index [0] for?  
Again, many thanks for your help!

Comment: The code splits `'KHOR<https://www.fleetmon.com/vessels/al-khor-f_0_11569260>'` to `["KHOR","https://www.fleetmon.com/vessels/al-khor-f_0_11569260>"]` and then gets the zeroth element of that list (`KHOR`)

Comment: Ahhh that makes sense! Thank you!